# Multiple TESTFLAGs in C++

Tags: c++, compilation

Our rather large C++ code base has a different debug flag for each module.  These are currently defined in the code like so:

```
#ifdef A_DEBUG

 {foo foo}

#endif
```

However, we have more than one of these flags.  So while

```
clearmake -C gnu TESTFLAG=-DA_DEBUG
```

works just great on one flag, I would love to be able to compile with more than one test flag at once, i.e., compile with A_DEBUG and B_DEBUG at the same time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

And

```
clearmake -C gnu TESTFLAG="-DA_DEBUG -DB_DEBUG"
```

does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, how about `clearmake -C gnu TESTFLAG="-DA_DEBUG -DB_DEBUG -DC_DEBUG"` ?